# How can you create a local http proxy in Qt to serve a file

Tags: proxy, qt4

Im trying to create a proxy on 127.0.0.1 that serves a file. The file itself is an .m3u8 playlist (HLS). Im trying to pass this to a MediaPlayer object.

Ive been told I cant simply pass the local path to the file to the MediaPlayer and that I must use a proxy.

the source path to the MediaPlayer would then be something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/playlist.m3u8.
```

What I need to know is how do I create a simple proxy server on 127.0.0.1 that would serve this file.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to create a web server to listen at port 8080? http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html

Comment: Ah. I will try this thanks for the link. If it helps. I was told this from BlackBerry support. I didn't quite understand myself. I will definitely try what you posted.